# When I press the button, I cannot change my Text values ​with setState()

Tags: flutter

When I press the button, I want the value of my _sicaklikSeviyesi variable to change and update it to the screen with setState(), but I can't. I've been dealing with this problem for the last 2 days, I couldn't find a solution for a song. Can you help me pls?

***Main Screen Codes :***

```
import 'package:akilli_okul_sistemleri/alert_dialog.dart';
import 'package:akilli_okul_sistemleri/bottom_info_bar.dart';
import 'package:akilli_okul_sistemleri/drawer_panel.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class AnaMenu extends StatefulWidget {
  const AnaMenu({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<AnaMenu> createState() => _AnaMenuState();
}

class _AnaMenuState extends State<AnaMenu> {
  BottomInfoBarState altPanel = BottomInfoBarState();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Akıllı Ev Sistemleri'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            altPanel.degisenDegerler();
            AlertBoxDialog.alertBoxCreator(
                context: context,
                title: "Başlık",
                desc: 'Açıklama',
                imageLocation: AlertBoxDialog.yuksekSicaklikLogo);
          },
          child: Text("ISI UYARISI"),
        ),
      ),
      drawer: DrawerPanel(),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomInfoBar(),
    );
  }
}
```

***Bottom Info Bar Codes :***

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:akilli_okul_sistemleri/ana_menu.dart';

class BottomInfoBar extends StatefulWidget {
  BottomInfoBar({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  BottomInfoBarState createState() => BottomInfoBarState();
}

class BottomInfoBarState extends State<BottomInfoBar> {
  Color _logoRengi = Colors.white;
  int _sicaklikSeviyesi = 15,
      _sesSeviyesi = 15,
      _hareketSeviyesi = 45,
      _isikSeviyesi = 75,
      _dumanSeviyesi = 20;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        boxShadow: [
          BoxShadow(color: Colors.black38, spreadRadius: 0, blurRadius: 10),
        ],
      ),
      child: ClipRRect(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
            topLeft: Radius.circular(15), topRight: Radius.circular(15)),
        child: BottomAppBar(
          color: Colors.orange[300],
          child: Row(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
            children: [
              _bottomContainerCreator(
                  Icons.local_fire_department, _sicaklikSeviyesi.toString()),
              _bottomContainerCreator(
                  Icons.record_voice_over, "%$_sesSeviyesi"),
              _bottomContainerCreator(
                  Icons.directions_walk, '%$_hareketSeviyesi'),
              _bottomContainerCreator(Icons.light, "%$_isikSeviyesi"),
              _bottomContainerCreator(Icons.cloud, "%$_dumanSeviyesi"),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  _bottomContainerCreator(IconData icon, String text) {
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.grey[700], borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0)),
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(3),
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(3),
      height: 60,
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
            child: Icon(
              icon,
              size: 27,
              color: _logoRengi,
            ),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 1),
            child: Text(
              text,
              style:
                  TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Colors.white),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  void degisenDegerler() {
    setState(() {
      _sicaklikSeviyesi = 100;
      if (_sicaklikSeviyesi < 20) {
        _logoRengi = Colors.blue;
      } else if (_sicaklikSeviyesi > 50) {
        _logoRengi = Colors.red;
      } else {
        _logoRengi = Colors.yellow;
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Does it at least give an error of some sort? If so, can you tell me what error you get?

Comment: yes when i push button i have this error `FlutterError (setState() called in constructor: BottomInfoBarState#5c987(lifecycle state: created, no widget, not mounted)`

Answer (score 0):

You can move the setState up the widget tree (in the AnaMenu widget). All widgets that depend on the value (in your case the color) will rebuild and update.

Try this code below for a simple function. If your bottombar doesn't require other logic. You might want to convert it to a Stateless widget

```
class AnaMenu extends StatefulWidget {
  const AnaMenu({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<AnaMenu> createState() => _AnaMenuState();
}

class _AnaMenuState extends State<AnaMenu> {
  late Color color;
  @override
  void initState() {
    color = Colors.blue;
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Akıllı Ev Sistemleri'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            setState(() {
              color = Colors.green;
            });
            // AlertBoxDialog.alertBoxCreator(
            //     context: context,
            //     title: "Başlık",
            //     desc: 'Açıklama',
            //     imageLocation: AlertBoxDialog.yuksekSicaklikLogo);
          },
          child: Text("ISI UYARISI"),
        ),
      ),
      // drawer: DrawerPanel(),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomInfoBar(color: color),
    );
  }
}

class BottomInfoBar extends StatefulWidget {
  final Color color;
  BottomInfoBar({required this.color, Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  BottomInfoBarState createState() => BottomInfoBarState();
}

class BottomInfoBarState extends State<BottomInfoBar> {
  // Color _logoRengi = Colors.white;
  late int _sicaklikSeviyesi;
  late int _sesSeviyesi;
  late int _hareketSeviyesi;
  late int _isikSeviyesi;
  late int _dumanSeviyesi;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _sicaklikSeviyesi = 15;
    _sesSeviyesi = 15;
    _hareketSeviyesi = 45;
    _isikSeviyesi = 75;
    _dumanSeviyesi = 20;
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        boxShadow: [
          BoxShadow(color: Colors.black38, spreadRadius: 0, blurRadius: 10),
        ],
      ),
      child: ClipRRect(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
            topLeft: Radius.circular(15), topRight: Radius.circular(15)),
        child: BottomAppBar(
          color: Colors.orange[300],
          child: Row(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
            children: [
              _bottomContainerCreator(
                  Icons.local_fire_department, _sicaklikSeviyesi.toString()),
              _bottomContainerCreator(
                  Icons.record_voice_over, "%$_sesSeviyesi"),
              _bottomContainerCreator(
                  Icons.directions_walk, '%$_hareketSeviyesi'),
              _bottomContainerCreator(Icons.light, "%$_isikSeviyesi"),
              _bottomContainerCreator(Icons.cloud, "%$_dumanSeviyesi"),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  _bottomContainerCreator(IconData icon, String text) {
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.grey[700], borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0)),
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(3),
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(3),
      height: 60,
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
            child: Icon(
              icon,
              size: 27,
              color: widget.color,
            ),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 1),
            child: Text(
              text,
              style:
                  TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Colors.white),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but actually my purpose is to fetch the sicaklikSeviyesi value from firebase and make it change on the screen instantly. For example temperature will change instantly
 and temp>30 ? icon color = red